# SSIS Lookup of another table

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

Okay,
So, here is the deal. I am taking a flat text file, cleaning it up, and putting it into a SQL Table in an SSIS package. This table includes employee numbers. I need to then connect to a different server, database, and table to then look up the employees email and their supervisor employee number based on their employee number (this email can change and the company only wants one master copy of this employee data table, so taking a copy of this table is not an option). I will then need to take what I got with the supervisor number and look up their email as well. These two emails will then need to be sent a single structured email. Is this possible without taking a local copy of the email address? This will need to be done for 500+ employee numbers a month. I cannot seem to wrap my head around this one.

Comment: Have you tried Lookup component or Merge Join component in Data Flow task, then select recordset as the destination and loop the recordset for sending mail task.

Comment: I have tried, but I cannot store this data in the history because I cannot store data from this DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with both tables as source components and do a Merge Join on employee number to match the rows from the two tables.

Same thing to match these records with a third source component to get the supervisor emails.

Comment: So, how would I loop through and send emails?

Comment: There are multiple ways.   Personally I would import all records to a staging table on a target server, and then call a stored procedure that iterates through that table and sends the mail.   But if you have to send the mail from SSIS, you can populate an object variable and loop through that.   Or a flat file.   Or a script component.  Multiple ways, like I said.

Comment: Hi Tab,
This is what I went about doing. I put the records into a staging table and have a link between my SQL databases that has a view pulled from the staging table and a table within the other database. This view is then called into an object variable and other variables are used to send the emails. Once I am done processing all of my data, it is then put into a history table and the staging table is truncated.